# How to properly send multiple actions in RTK?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

Making the switch to RTK, and encountered the problem that it is not clear how to properly rewrite the following construction using RTK.

```js
const toggleModal = (): (dispatch: Dispatch) => void => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch): void => {
    this.clearModal()(dispatch);
    dispatch({ type: 'TOGGLE_MODAL' });
  };
};
```

Comment: This looks like it's only one action using the thunk middleware. It doesn't need to be rewritten at all with redux-toolkit. redux-toolkit provides `createAsyncThunk`, but this doesn't apply to your code.

Comment: toggleModal and clearModal these actions. If I implement toggleModal with createAction, how can I call clearModal at the same time?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The code you're showing should work as it is with redux-toolkit. If it does not work, please provide details about any errors.

Comment: I will modify the above code and create two actions:
`const toggleModal = createAction("TOGGLE");
const clearModal = createAction("CLEAR");`
Is there any way to send clearModal at the same time as sending toggleModal?
No errors, I'm interested in how to dispatch one action depending on the dispatch of the other.

Comment: You cannot send them at the exact same time, as JavaScript is single threaded. One of the actions has to be dispatched after the other. If you want to wait for an async action to complete before dispatching another one, this can be done by using async/await in your thunk or returning a promise. This has been answered many times on SO as well.